# jasper repor plugin 2.0.0.RC1 on grails 3.x doesn't work

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a PDF report on grails 3.3.1 with japser report plugin.

I follow the instructions on this page: https://puneetbehl.github.io/grails-jasper/docs/index.html#installation

but when I download the PDF I always receive a empty pdf (or an empty XML).

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
 compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
 compile "org.grails:grails-core"
 compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
 compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
 compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
 compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
 compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
 compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
 compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
 compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
 compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"

 compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:2.0.0.RC1"

 console "org.grails:grails-console"
 profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
 runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
 runtime "com.h2database:h2"
 testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
 testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
 testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
 testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

}

in index.gsp

```
<g:jasperReport
    jasper="example_a4"
    format="PDF,HTML,XML"
    name="test">
</g:jasperReport>
```

the example_a4.jrxml (under src/webapps/reports):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.4.3.final utlizzo versione della libreria JasperReports6.4.3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="example_a4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="563f0f65-00af-4be9-84c2-f3c504b70afc">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="220" y="20" width="270" height="30" uuid="b4362a25-8b6d-4b9b-a743-56c5d90ba75e"/>
            <text><![CDATA[ESEMPIO]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="250" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="eefc514b-4904-4cf1-bf5d-42df2137621f"/>
            <text><![CDATA[PIE DI PAGINA]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperPrint xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/print http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperprint.xsd" name="ddt" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" topMargin="20" leftMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" rightMargin="20" locale="it_IT" timezone="Europe/Rome">
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.start.page.index" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.end.page.index" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xml.page.count" value="1"/>
<origin band="background"/>
<origin band="title"/>
 <origin band="pageHeader"/>
 <origin band="columnHeader"/>
 <origin band="detail"/>
 <origin band="columnFooter"/>
 <origin band="pageFooter"/>
 <style name="Title" fontName="Arial" fontSize="26" isBold="true"/>
 <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
 <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
 <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
 <page/>
 </jasperPrint>
```

I don't receive any errors.

Comment: Try to set *whenNoDataType* property of report as *AllSectionsNoDetail*.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you. What I have to in this case? Remove the question?